# Why is my Javascript variable not being set outside of this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am attempting to get the dimensions of an image to use later in my script. Selecting the img element directly with jQuery works fine and is easier, however it does not function in webkit browsers (the image is not loaded at the time of the function call). I'm trying to implement this solution where the variables are set after the image loads by using the jquery load() function.

Why are my variables not being set as desired?

```
function startSlider() {
  if (1 == 1) {
  var bImg = $('#banner img');
  var bWidth = 111, bHeight = 222;
  $("<img/>")
    .attr("src", $(bImg).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
      bWidth = this.width;
      bHeight = this.height;
      console.log('inner: ' + this.height);
    });
  console.log('outer: ' + bHeight);
  }
}

 $(window).load(startSlider(skin));
```

Output

```
outer: 222
inner: 333
```

Example Source

```
<div id="banner">
   <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe you get "outer" line **after** "inner" one

Comment: Thanks, I had them mistakenly reversed.

Comment: what the image is created by javascript? or just create by html tag ?

Comment: The image is native in the document, it's not created by javascript. `$('#banner img')` refers to an HTML tag in the loaded document. I'll add sample source.

Comment: Why do you do `$(bImg)` when bImg is already a jQuery object? Set load before you set the src. And learn about asynchronous and synchronous calls.

Comment: If I use bImg without it being a jQuery selector I get an error that `bImg.load()` is not a function. If this problem was due to the callback not being executed, or being executed more then one time, would I not get either no log output or multiple outputs from within the callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.load()` is an asynchronous callback, meaning it will occur at the time the browser has finished downloading the image file.

You are binding `.load()` to your image, then immediately logging the height. Because the `.load()` callback hasn't yet run, it will output the default height.

You need to wait until `.load()` has finished executing before continuing with any further logic that relies on the image height.

Comment: Is that not what I'm doing? `console.log('inner: ' + this.height);` outputs the correct value of 333

Comment: This is correct, you just have to remember that your callback function (including this console.log) will be called at some point in the future, not straight away. Assuming you want to kick off some other function once you have the image height, you might do this: http://jsfiddle.net/P6dqv/

Comment: This still doesn't set the correct value: [http://jsfiddle.net/P6dqv/](http://jsfiddle.net/P6dqv/)

Comment: Ok, I could be misunderstanding what you're trying to do here. You're loading creating an image in memory (not appending to the DOM), and giving it the same src as the original image. Your new memory image won't have a width/height, because it needs to be appended to the DOM for this calculation to occur. Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/P6dqv/3/

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. If the image object in memory doesn't have a calculated width/height then how does `console.log('inner: ' + this.height);` return the correct height value of the image? [http://jsfiddle.net/xmW7J/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/xmW7J/8/)

Comment: @RyanFisher My mistake, it is possible to retrieve the width/height of an image outside of the DOM using the native .width/.height properties of the image. My original answer on WHY your "outer" height check fails still applies: http://jsfiddle.net/P6dqv/5/

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. I now have a much better understanding of callbacks and the nature of how asynchronous methods work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `startSlider()` called and `$("<img/>")` is not ready or is not completed loaded,that's why you can't change your variable.

make sure you are using [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) on your code, DOMContentLoaded is event will be fire when parsing of element is finished, in jquery you can use this function

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('DOM Loaded (DOMContentLoaded)');
        //place your function in here
      });
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added my invocation of the function: `$(window).load(startSlider());` The function isn't being called until the DOM is loaded (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    startSlider();
});
```